# Differences between Using NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject and dataUsingEncoding to make up the HTTP body in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, http

I have seen two kinds of methods to make up the HTTP body.
First one is:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://example.com")  
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)  
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"  
let postString = "id=13&name=Jack"  
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Second one is:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://example.com")  
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)  
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"  
let params = ["id":"13", "name":"Jack"] as Dictionary<String, String>
var err: NSError?
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
```

When I directly print out the request.HTTPBody the data is different. So I am wondering are there any differences between these two methods in terms of the implementation of the server side? Assuming I'am using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

there're two format data.

in code using `postString.dataUsingEncoding` it will send data in urlencoded format. In client you must set request's Content-Type header to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` or something like `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8"`

in code using `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject` it will send data in json format. In client you must set request's Content-Type header field to `"application/json"`

I'm iOS dev so I don't know about format's effect to server side PHP. to answer your question you must find difference between `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `application/json` format in server side